# An issue with postinst-intercept scripts

Tags: yocto

I trying to integrate Yocto 2.6.2 due to higher version packages requests from Software team. Except regular `oe bitbake`, in our company we have another build system which is based on python also. I am not familiar too much with it but it invokes bitbake too. Just it fetches the layers from company servers because it is not able to do it from the net and put some additional data. The issue is following. With regular bitbake everything is fine and the build goes smoothly. When I run our proprietary build system it fails on `do_rootfs` with the following reason copied from the log:

```
**NOTE: Running intercept scripts:**
**NOTE: > Executing update_icon_cache intercept ...**
**NOTE: Exit code 127. Output:**
**/home/w23698/projects/btstmp/builds/home/w23698/projects/proj_csc5_clean/proj_csc5/srcMirror/build/tmp/work/csc5-poky-linux-gnueabi/ww-image/1.0-r0/intercept_scripts-12c5ef04e386052464955905a231f7ec3a3eb8c0452bbf7c1cd0f436ca99cbf7/update_icon_cache: 6: /home/w23698/projects/btstmp/builds/home/w23698/projects/proj_csc5_clean/proj_csc5/srcMirror/build/tmp/work/csc5-poky-linux-gnueabi/ww-image/1.0-r0/intercept_scripts-12c5ef04e386052464955905a231f7ec3a3eb8c0452bbf7c1cd0f436ca99cbf7/update_icon_cache: /home/w23698/projects/btstmp/builds/home/w23698/projects/proj_csc5_clean/proj_csc5/srcMirror/build/tmp/work/csc5-poky-linux-gnueabi/ww-image/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native//gdk-pixbuf-2.0/gdk-pixbuf-query-loaders: not found**

**ERROR: The postinstall intercept hook 'update_icon_cache' failed, details in /home/w23698/projects/btstmp/builds/home/w23698/projects/proj_csc5_clean/proj_csc5/srcMirror/build/tmp/work/csc5-poky-linux-gnueabi/ww-image/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_rootfs**

**DEBUG: Python function do_rootfs finished**
**ERROR: Function failed: do_rootfs**
```

In the normal bitbake the invoked intercept (update_gio_module_cache intercept) script is very different and it passes.
Where the decision which intercept script to call is made?

I notified that all the intercept scripts in the proprietary build system are chmoded to x. I made one very simple try to match the access flags as per original yocto poky layer. It didn't help.

Comment: It can't find native `gdk-pixbuf-query-loaders` created by [gdk-pixbuf](https://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit.cgi/poky/tree/meta/recipes-gnome/gdk-pixbuf/gdk-pixbuf_2.38.0.bb) recipe with `do_install_append_class-native`. Did you try to clean it with  `bitbake -c cleansstate gdk-pixbuf` before rebuild?

Comment: not only that. I erase whole build dir, except conf. and nothing...

Comment: Did you try to check if `/home/w23698/projects/btstmp/builds/home/w23698/projects/proj_csc5_clean/proj_csc5/srcMirror/build/tmp/work/csc5-poky-linux-gnueabi/ww-image/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native//gdk-pixbuf-2.0/gdk-pixbuf-query-loaders` exists, and if not, is there a `gdk-pixbuf-query-loaders` file somewhere in `recipe-sysroot-native` folder?

Comment: yes, I did...but no such file or directory.

Comment: In your image recipe, try to add `DEPENDS = "gdk-pixbuf-native"`

Comment: Thanks Nayfe. Unfortunately it does not solve the issue. Our corporate build system is based on scons (scons.org), and it is a wrapper of yocto. The people responsible are dealing with it now. And my investigation shown that depending on access flags yocto executes different items.

Comment: Thanks for access flags results! I was getting similar problem with missing GTK folder because of script running after I accidentally changed access flags on meta folder.

Comment: @Mischo5500 Thanks for the lead! My do_rootfs was failing with the same error but on another postinst-intercept script. The issue was indeed the access flags on these files. I had recently moved mt Yocto folder across Linux installs and this caused the flags from all layers to change (644 became 755). A "git restore *" on my poky directory and all was solved! Cheers!

Comment: I had the same problem, and the comments here are correct - see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70841836/yocto-postinstall-intercept-hook-update-desktop-database-error/74807714#74807714