# Yocto: postinstall intercept hook "update_desktop_database" error

Tags: yocto, bitbake, openembedded

I am trying to build custom linux image using yocto. The set up is;

- Ubuntu 20.04 on Oracle Virtual Machine
- Yocto release **dunfell**

It gives this error

> NOTE: Exit code 127. Output:
> /home/user234/yocto-project/image/build/tmp/work/qemux86-poky-linux/core-image-minimal/1.0-r0/intercept_scripts-1bf6a9721f164ba99b8a07325a9c3fe0f21a700fea55c8351519b59cf02d0aca/update_desktop_database:
> 7: update-desktop-database: not found

> ERROR: The postinstall intercept hook 'update_desktop_database' failed, details in /home/user234/yocto-project/image/build/tmp/work/qemux86-poky-linux/core-image-minimal/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_rootfs

The problem only occures in Virtual Machine Environment, It works fine with native linux environment on my other machine.

I have installed the ***desktop-file-utils*** and I can run from my shell manually. Somehow, bitbake is unable to detect it. Does someone know the solution?

Comment: Are you installing any extra packages?, what image are you building?

Answer (score 1):

You can resolve this issue immediately by patching poky sources to skip execution of "update_desktop_database" in this path:

poky/scripts/postinst-intercepts/update_desktop_database

Just comment the line.

It may happen again for other scripts. Just do the same for the other scripts. Finally, the do_rootfs task will complete successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem (without virtual machine, you will see that this part is unrelated). **The issue is with file permissions of the Yocto sources**, or part of them. In my particular case the DevOps have set the POSIX file permissions on the entire Yocto source directory to `777`, i.e. `-rwxrwxrwx`. Don't ask me why.

In the OP's case it seems like the Yocto sources may have been copied to the virtual machine with a help of some permission-less file system, like FAT32, which results in the same outcome. A good example is copying the sources with a USB flash drive formatted with FAT32. YMMV, this may probably be relevant for ACLs as well, I haven't tried to fiddle with that.

In my opinion, this should be considered as a bug in bitbake. If the source files permissions can cause such an unpredictable behavior, they have to be verified before or during the build, and the user must be informed by generating an error.

This is clearly irrelevant to the OP by now, hope somebody finds it useful.

Comment: So having `777` permission causes an issue? What permission should I use?

Comment: @fabda01, normally you don't "use" any specific permissions. Working under Linux OS implies all kinds of permissions per use case, file type, users involved, and so on. The right thing here is to avoid losing the normal file permissions, for instance by copying them using a file system that does not support permissions used by Linux. I do believe there is a very specific bug in BitBake that makes such builds to fail, however in order to prove it one like me would have to spend a while searching for it. On the other hand, I didn't collect enough info about the case to open a bug.

Comment: I see. Sorry for my bad English. I actually tried to say "What are the (normal) recipe file permissions I should `chmod` to before calling bitbake?" I had the error after changing it to `777` and `755`, so what worked for you?

Comment: You should not change permissions, that's the thing. Say someone has Yocto project on a Linux machine and can successfully build on it. All files in the main Yocto project directory have their respective permissions. They can vary, for instance executable files will have the rwx for user/group/other, while non-executable ones will probably have rw- for the same. I do understand that making it 777 seems to do no harm, but it does. So, if you want to transfer the entire Yocto project directory, tar it first on the source, and untar on the target to retain the original permissions.