# core-image-base/base.1.0-r0/rootfs/packages does not exist

Tags: build, embedded-linux, yocto, imx8

I just tried to build an rootfs-image about imx8 (cpu: imx8mp-lpddr4-evk) compiled by yocto, but it fails with the following errors:
*(Compile enviroment= Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.15.0-43-generic x86_64))*

```
NOTE: Executing postinstall for package: wpa-supplicant ...
NOTE:
NOTE: Executing postinstall for package: xxhash ...
NOTE:
NOTE: Running intercept scripts:
NOTE: > Executing update_mime_database intercept ...
NOTE: Exit code 1. Output:
Updating MIME database... this may take a while.
Directory '/home/hdcvt/imx-yacto-bsp/build-fsys/tmp/work/imx8mp_lpddr4_evk-poky-linux/core-image-base/1.0-r0/rootfs/packages' does not exist!

ERROR: The postinstall intercept hook 'update_mime_database' failed, details in /home/hdcvt/imx-yacto-bsp/build-fsys/tmp/work/imx8mp_lpddr4_evk-poky-linux/core-image-base/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_rootfs
```

With The missing Packages directory,try my solutions belowes:

- Make the directory of packages (mkdir) ,  but still same error (I thought the program has rm command).
  so when compiling ,I has been giving mkdir command.  when it's OK ,but  other errors shown, (lack of other files). More and more bugs, and can not be solved,I thought it's wrong direction.
- Create new packages and deal with packages as undeletable -> Error found to rootfs.py

```
    class PkgRootfs(DpkgOpkgRootfs):
    def __init__(self, d, manifest_dir, progress_reporter=None, logcatcher=None):
        super(PkgRootfs, self).__init__(d, progress_reporter, logcatcher)
        self.log_check_regex = '^E:'
        self.log_check_expected_regexes = \
        [
            "^E: Unmet dependencies."
        ]

        bb.utils.remove(self.image_rootfs, True) //----error is reported here-------
        bb.utils.remove(self.d.getVar('MULTILIB_TEMP_ROOTFS'), True)
        self.manifest = PkgManifest(d, manifest_dir)
        self.pm = DpkgPM(d, d.getVar('IMAGE_ROOTFS'),
                         d.getVar('PACKAGE_ARCHS'),
                         d.getVar('DPKG_ARCH'))
```

So I blocked this sentence, not only are there no fewer bugs, but there are more.

As the same ,compiling the cross compilation toolchain has the same problem.

I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.

Comment: Why is this tagged with 'c'?

Comment: This may be a case similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70841836/yocto-postinstall-intercept-hook-update-desktop-database-error/

Comment: You can try this idea: https://community.toradex.com/t/rootfs-packages-folder-does-not-exist-build-fail-imx8mp/16050