# Error occured while building Yocto linux for AM572x

Tags: yocto

I am using a custom build yocto linux image for AM572x- IDK (TMDSIDK5729). While building yocto image i got an error giveni below. Please help me in this..

ERROR: core-image-minimal-1.0-r0 do_rootfs: The postinstall intercept hook 'update_mime_database' failed, details in /LinuxFiles/poky_am572x/poky/build/tmp-default-glibc/work/am57xx_evm-oe-linux-gnueabi/core-image-minimal/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_rootfs
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /LinuxFiles/poky_am572x/poky/build/tmp-default-glibc/work/am57xx_evm-oe-linux-gnueabi/core-image-minimal/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_rootfs.18451
ERROR: Task (/LinuxFiles/poky_am572x/poky/meta/recipes-core/images/core-image-minimal.bb:do_rootfs) failed with exit code '1'
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 2385 tasks of which 2384 didn't need to be rerun and 1 failed.

Comment: The log you provided just tells you the update_mime_database failed. The details are needed to check what was wrong.

Comment: Yocto is installed in the folder poky_am572x. Accidentally deleted some folders from my PC, which is outside the installation directory. After that i got these errors.

Comment: Alright, can you restart a compilation from scratch then ?

Comment: I removed the build folder and compiled from scratch. Again i am having the same issues.

Comment: Could you provide the error message then ? See the line `details in ....`

Comment: log file is too large, so i pasted the last steps of bitbake build as shown above.

Comment: My bitbake build directory is in a hard disk other than linux OS installed.

Comment: There's no need to provide all the log output but only the interesting part, please edit your question to leave only what's needed. Your error is simply "update-mime-database: command not found" (I don't know the solution yet)

Comment: Error message in log file added below

NOTE: Running intercept scripts: NOTE: > Executing update_mime_database intercept ... NOTE: Exit code 127. Output: Updating MIME database... this may take a while. /core-image-minimal/1.0-r0/intercept_scripts-e631fa1876ab0ba0faf230c211a74320c1130f9db832cf6a069f4476cd8400ca/update_mime_database: line 8: update-mime-database: command not found

ERROR: The postinstall intercept hook 'update_mime_database' failed,

Comment: Probably has an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70841836/yocto-postinstall-intercept-hook-update-desktop-database-error/74807714#74807714